# launch.asp error when launching a course from LMS

Tags: machine-learning, scorm

Just wondering if anyone has seen these type of issues?

One: When a learner launches a scorm package from our LMS they are preseted with a blank screen "launch.asp error". They are unable to take the course even though they meet all technical requirements. It is a real problem for us and we have exhaused all troubleshooting options. HELP please.

Two: When the learners complete a course and launch a exam it never shows up in their achievment page. We think the course window looses the connection to the parent window (LMS) so when they complete the exam it can't write back to the LMS so it stays on their learning plan page.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Nancy

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information.  Which LMS are you using - is it one you've built, or one that is provided by another company?  Where does the SCORM package come from - again, is it one you've built yourself, or bought from somewhere?

However, there is something you can try that will help you narrow down where the problem is.

SCORM Cloud is an LMS that can be used to test all things relating to SCORM, where you can create a free account.  Go to http://cloud.scorm.com/ and open a free account.  Load the package into that LMS, and see if it runs.  If it works perfectly, then the package is fine and it is your LMS that has the problem - contact your LMS provider, with details of the package you are trying to run, and see what they say.

If the package does not run in SCORM cloud, then it is the package itself which is at fault.  Contact the author of the package to see what the problem is.

By the sounds of it, the package is trying to run an ASP application, which the LMS may not support, but without knowing specifics, it's hard to tell.

As for the exam problem, that's something your LMS provider needs to address (unless you are the provider, in which case we need some technical details).

Comment: Thank you.It is an off the shelf product called LearnFlex. I will try the SCORM Cloud